# Why have attached properties been added to XAML?

Tags: xaml

I have looked at various examples and read about attached properties. However it is still not clear to me why they are required or better. Look at this example:

`<DockPanel>
  <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Top">Hello</CheckBox>
</DockPanel>`

DockPanel.Dock is an attached property and it is clear what the intention is: not very element should have or need an individual property that would allow it to define its docking behavior. Same goes for grid's row and columns definitions. But why not express things like this instead:

`<DockPanel>
  <Docked Location="Top">
    <CheckBox>Hello</CheckBox>
  </Docked>
</DockPanel>`

Similar would be possible for grids with row and column tags.

Was this a pure design decision or are there other reasons that make attached properties the better or the only solution?

Comment: I love it if a questions gets down voted without comment...how can I possibly improve it if I don't know what's wrong about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example might be applied for just one case, even frequent, but you should not rely on *just one* attached property.

Suppose, for instance, that you wish to mark more than just one attached property, as follows:

```
<DockPanel>
  <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextBlock.FontSize="16">Hello</CheckBox>
</DockPanel>
```

How messy would be the equivalent "encapsulated" way?

I myself would add another viewpoint, despite is just *mine*. The XAML notation often denotes the objects structure: an element represents a class (instance), whereas an attribute a property. Your pattern would fight against the ability to set a property as follows:

```
<DockPanel>
  <DockPanel.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY=3" />
  </DockPanel.RenderTransform>
</DockPanel>
```

This is a particular element pattern which denotes an alternative way to define a property (e.g. RenderTransform) content (i.e. the actual transform instance).

UPDATE: I'd also add another thing about *what* should be inserted as child of a certain container (the DockPanel in your example). The "Docked" should be an actual child or just a virtual container being not part of the visual/logic tree? Then , supposing walking up the visual/logic tree, should you find this element or not? If not, in which way should you get the "Docked" value?

Now, I am not sure whether my answer is satisfying you, but...feel free to specify better what you don't like in the attached-properties pattern, and maybe you'll reach the point!

Comment: I "like" attached properties and your example with the two different properties really does explain why they are useful. I totally missed that!